# Foreach is not working in JMeter with JSON extractor

Tags: jmeter

Have the following response payload, I want to fetch the `Order Number` and `Total Order Number` and pass it on to a `for each` controller, but it is not working.

I am able to fetch the total number, but it is not passing to for each controller, may be doing some mistake in the variable assignment,

```
{
    "orderDetails": {
        "orderCode": 490278,
        "studyCode": "test_2"
    },
    "sites": [
        {
            "orderCode": 490278,
            "siteRecid": 16521,
            "siteId": "11001"
        }
    ],
    "orders": [
        {
            "orderNumber": 4027,
            "siteName": "flipKart",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart",
            "orderAmount": 10
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 4590,
            "siteName": "flipKart_1",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 1",
            "orderAmount": 20
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1678,
            "siteName": "flipKart_2",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 2",
            "orderAmount": 30
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1762,
            "siteName": "flipKart_3",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 3",
            "orderAmount": 40
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1566,
            "siteName": "flipKart_4",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 4",
            "orderAmount": 50
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1432,
            "siteName": "flipKart_5",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 5",
            "orderAmount": 60
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1089,
            "siteName": "flipKart_6",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 6",
            "orderAmount": 70
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 9078,
            "siteName": "flipKart_7",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 7",
            "orderAmount": 80
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 4508,
            "siteName": "flipKart_8",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 8",
            "orderAmount": 90
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 4278,
            "siteName": "flipKart_9",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 9",
            "orderAmount": 100
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 9028,
            "siteName": "flipKart_10",
            "siteNameCode": "flipKart 10",
            "orderAmount": 110
        }
    ]
}
```

Fetch the total number of orders,
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For each controller is not running. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine, in the ForEach Controller you need to use just `OrderNumberTotal` without `${}`, take a look at [ForEach Controller documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) example screenshot:

[image]

there are variable names like `inputVar`, not variable reference like `${inputVar}`

[image]

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.

More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)